# C++: "expected ;" in declaration in template

Tags: c++, templates

I've been running into the following problem inside a member function of a templated class:

```
#include <map>
using std::map;
template <typename A,typename B>
class C {
  public:
    B f(const A&,const B&) const;
  private:
    map<A,B> D;
};
template <typename A,typename B>
B C<A,B>::f(const A&a,const B&b) const {
   map<A,B>::const_iterator x = D.find(a);
   if(x == D.end())
     return b;
   else
     return x->second;
}
```

When I have g++ compile this I get the following error:

```
Bug.C: In member function 'B C<A,B>::f(const A&, const B&) const':
Bug.C:12: error:expected ';' before 'x'
Bug.C:13: error: 'x' was not declared in this scope
```

However, when I make a non-templated version of the class and function, with A and B both being int it compiles without a problem.  The error is a little mystifying since I can't imagine why it wants a ';' before the 'x'.

Comment: wow, how quickly can you get 3 people to post 3 blocks of identical code?

Comment: I'm wondering which one he's gonna pick as the correct one

Comment: @HappyYellowFace hopefully whichever one breaks whatever pact they have and updates with an explanation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: BTW, naming a C++ source file `Bug.C` is just asking for trouble, and in future please tell us your compiler version.

Comment: What version of gcc did you use? When I try your example, I get a very clear error: error.cpp: In member function ‘B C<A, B>::f(const A&, const B&) const’:
error.cpp:12:4: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::map<A, B>::const_iterator’ because ‘std::map<A, B>’ is a dependent scope
error.cpp:12:29: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘x’
error.cpp:13:7: error: ‘x’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: @Arrieta: I just tried it on my macbook at home.  It's running 4.2.1 (I know that that's pretty old, but that's what comes with xcode).  I don't know what version I have at work (I can't access that computer now).  But I'm glad to see that newer versions of gcc have a more comprehensible error message.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're missing a `typename`:

```
typename map<A,B>::const_iterator x = D.find(a);
```

Please read [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords). The reason you need `typename` here is because `A` and `B` are template parameters which means that the meaning of `::const_iterator` **depends** on what `A` and `B` are. While to a human the name `const_iterator` makes it obvious that this is an iterator type, to a compiler it doesn't know if this is a type, a data member, etc.

The compiler will do a syntax check on the first pass before templates are instantiated and by adding `typename` you letting the compiler know to parse the `map<A,B>::const_iterator` as a type.

Also, there is a special rule in C++ (shamefully stolen from the linked question):

> A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is
>   dependent on a template-parameter is assumed not to name a type unless
>   the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is qualified
>   by the keyword typename.

If you do not add `typename`, the compiler **has to assume that it is not a type**.

Comment: I beat you by 6 seconds. 8v)

Comment: The answer's comprehensive - I also find it interesting that the error message given in the question is so misleading. C++ compilers are known for sometimes bizarre error messages, but on my machine g++ 4.7.2 gives a far more helpful `error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::map<A, B>::const_iterator’ because ‘std::map<A, B>’ is a dependent scope`

Answer (score 2):

You have missed the keyword [`typename`](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html), which is required before a qualified name that refers to a type and depends on a template parameter:

```
typename map<A,B>::const_iterator x = D.find(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `typename`:

```
typename map<A,B>::const_iterator x = D.find(a);
```

Explanation:
`typename` states that the name that follows should be treated as a type. Otherwise, names are interpreted to refer to non-types.